# How to change color of grouping text in asp panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I have multiple panel in my web form. Let say I want to change one of my panel's grouping text (only) to red, how can I do that? I know that grouping Text is `legend`.

Here, I have my code that will change the grouping text color (only), but it change my **ALL** of my other panel. I only want to change **one** of my panel but not all.

```
<style>
    legend {color:red}
</style>

<asp:Panel CssClass="legend" ID="Panel1" runat="server" GroupingText="My Panel">...</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

How you define the `CssClass="legend"`, hope that the following snippet will solve the issue: For your special requirement of setting `legend` for a particular panel you need to specify the panel Id while defining the style:

```
<style>
        #Panel1 legend { color: Red; font-size:25px }
        legend { color: Black; font-size:25px }
</style>
```

The above snippet will set `color: Red;` for `Panel1` and others remains in `black`. You can Define `CssClass="legend` with required style set, that will help you to style the  `GroupingText` property of `<asp:Panel ..>`

Comment: umm what do you mean by required style set? can you give an example? Thanks

Comment: example is already given `legend { color: Red; font-size:45px }` required style set means; styling elements for  `GroupingText` like `color`, `font`,`font-size` etc

Comment: For your special requirement of setting legend for a particular panel you need to specify the panel Id while defining the style: please take a look into the updates

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try